# Spring Mail working but sudden "Got bad greeting from SMTP host"

Tags: java, spring, email

This past week, my email service project has been working completely fine, but today when I try to run it in Eclipse it throws a:

```
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Got bad greeting from SMTP host: mail.test.com, port: 25, response: 554 mail.test.com
. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Got bad greeting from SMTP host: mail.test.com, port: 25, response: 554 mail.test.com
```

What could be the sudden cause of this? Now, my SpringBoot main class won't end, I have to manually terminate it.

Comment: Your edit doesn't clarify things.  Where is `"mail.test.com"` and have you talked to the admin of the server?

Comment: Yeah, I will do that, i didn't realize that was what the error was. It's a test email that the admin set up, I will talk to them about it, thank you. I just wanted to know what was the reasoning behind this thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SMTP error 554 is kind of generic.

It usually means the remote host has decided it will not accept the message you are attempting to send (maybe because your sending server is blacklisted), and the rejection is permanent.

You need to talk to the admin on the receiving server (mail.test.com) to find out why your message is being rejected.